# Printer status stopped and doesn't print

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, canon, cups-lpd

I have a Canon Laser Shot LBP6200d and am running Ubuntu 16.04. The printer did not have a driver in the database therefore I installed the 64 bit Linux drivers from the canon website and once I did that Linux identified my printer. First when I sent files to print the status showed complete even though the file was not printed. After that, following a guide I replaced the pdftops file. Now when I print anything the status is stopped.

`lpinfo -v` gives this:

```
network lpd
network beh
direct ccp
network socket
network https
network ipp
direct cnusb:/dev/usb/lp2
network ipps
network http
network ipp14
direct usb://Canon/LBP6200?serial=0000A1C4O8SI
direct hp
direct hpfax
```

So I can see that the printer is recognized

`lsmod | grep usb` gives:

```
usblp                  20480  0
usb_storage            69632  1 uas
usbnet                 45056  1 cdc_ether
mii                    16384  1 usbnet
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure
Applications Processor
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 413c:8187 Dell Computer Corp. DW375 Bluetooth
Module
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:8184 Dell Computer Corp. F3607gw v2 Mobile
Broadband Module
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0101:0007  
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 04a9:271b Canon, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching
Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ca:1814 Ricoh Co., Ltd HD Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching
Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Running `ls -l /dev/usb/lp* /dev/bus/usb/*/*` gave:

```
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   0 Oct  5 21:10 /dev/bus/usb/001/001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   1 Oct  5 21:10 /dev/bus/usb/001/002
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   2 Oct  5 21:11 /dev/bus/usb/001/003
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 128 Oct  5 21:10 /dev/bus/usb/002/001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 129 Oct  5 21:10 /dev/bus/usb/002/002
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 131 Oct  5 21:11 /dev/bus/usb/002/004
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 132 Oct  5 21:11 /dev/bus/usb/002/005
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 133 Oct  5 21:11 /dev/bus/usb/002/006
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 137 Oct  5 21:21 /dev/bus/usb/002/010
crw-rw-r-- 1 root lp   189, 138 Oct  5 21:21 /dev/bus/usb/002/011
crw-rw---- 1 root lp   180,   2 Oct  5 21:21 /dev/usb/lp2
```

Finally I ran `sudo usb_printerid /dev/usb/lp2` since the printer was connected there and I got:

```
GET_DEVICE_ID string:
MFG:Canon;MDL:LBP6200;CMD:CAPT;VER:3.0;CLS:PRINTER;DES:Canon LBP6200
```

So it is pretty clear that the printer has been installed and recognized. The drivers seem to be working and the system knows the proper path to the printer. (Everything was pretty much the same before I replaced `pdftops`) I also know that the printer is working because it works properly on Windows 10.

If someone could guide me it would be great. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I also ran `tail -f /var/log/syslog` with the printer unplugged and then while it was running plugged it back in. This is the output I got after I plugged in the printer:

```
Oct  5 21:21:06 phantom-Latitude-E6410 kernel: [  620.069201] usb
2-1.2: Product: Canon CAPT USB Device
Oct  5 21:21:06 phantom-Latitude-E6410 kernel: [  620.069205] usb
2-1.2: Manufacturer: Canon
Oct  5 21:21:06 phantom-Latitude-E6410 kernel: [  620.069208] usb
2-1.2: SerialNumber: 0000A1C4O8SI
Oct  5 21:21:06 phantom-Latitude-E6410 kernel: [  620.072122] usblp
2-1.2:1.0: usblp2: USB Bidirectional printer dev 11 if 0 alt 0 proto 2
vid  0x04A9 pid 0x271B
Oct  5 21:21:06 phantom-Latitude-E6410 mtp-probe: checking bus 2,
device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2"
Oct  5 21:21:06 phantom-Latitude-E6410 mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 11
was not an MTP device
Oct  5 21:21:06 phantom-Latitude-E6410 systemd[1]: Reached target
Printer.
Oct  5 21:21:07 phantom-Latitude-E6410 systemd[1]: Starting Automatic
USB/Bluetooth printer setup
(-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1d.0-usb2-2\x2d1-2\x2d1.2)...
Oct  5 21:21:07 phantom-Latitude-E6410 udev-configure-printer[3402]:
add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2
Oct  5 21:21:07 phantom-Latitude-E6410 udev-configure-printer[3402]:
device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2
Oct  5 21:21:07 phantom-Latitude-E6410 udev-configure-printer[3402]:
MFG:Canon MDL:LBP6200 SERN:- serial:0000A1C4O8SI
Oct  5 21:21:07 phantom-Latitude-E6410 colord-sane: [bjnp]
create_broadcast_socket: ERROR - bind socket to local address failed -
Cannot assign requested address
Oct  5 21:21:12 phantom-Latitude-E6410 kernel: [  625.183617] usblp2:
removed
Oct  5 21:21:12 phantom-Latitude-E6410 kernel: [  625.190449] usblp
2-1.2:1.0: usblp2: USB Bidirectional printer dev 11 if 0 alt 0 proto 2
vid 0x04A9 pid 0x271B
Oct  5 21:21:12 phantom-Latitude-E6410 udev-configure-printer[3402]:
URI contains USB serial number
Oct  5 21:21:12 phantom-Latitude-E6410 udev-configure-printer[3402]:
URI match: usb://Canon/LBP6200?serial=0000A1C4O8SI
Oct  5 21:21:12 phantom-Latitude-E6410 udev-configure-printer[3402]:
URI of detected printer: usb://Canon/LBP6200?serial=0000A1C4O8SI,
normalized: canon lbp6200 serial 0000a1c4o8si
Oct  5 21:21:12 phantom-Latitude-E6410 udev-configure-printer[3402]:
URI of print queue: usb://Canon/LBP6200?serial=0000A1C4O8SI,
normalized: canon  lbp6200 serial 0000a1c4o8si
Oct  5 21:21:12 phantom-Latitude-E6410 udev-configure-printer[3402]:
Queue ipp://localhost/printers/Canon-LBP6200 has matching device URI
Oct  5 21:21:12 phantom-Latitude-E6410 udev-configure-printer[3402]:
URI of print queue: cnusb:/dev/usb/lp2, normalized: cnusb dev usb lp2
Oct  5 21:21:12 phantom-Latitude-E6410 systemd[1]: Started Automatic
USB/Bluetooth printer setup
(-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1d.0-usb2-2\x2d1-2\x2d1.2).
```

I believe that the error is somewhere here but I am unable to find it.